# Test Class which uses object Geocoder Internaly

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I have a utility class which downloads data from the internet.

```
public class MyHelper{
    Context mContext;
    public MyHelper(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public List<String> getDataForDate(DateTime dateTime) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        //
       }
}
```

And a Unit test

```
public class MyHelperTest{
    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Test
    public void is_not_empty() {
        MyHelper helper = new MyHelper(context);
        assertTrue("Size", (helper.getDataForDate(DateTime.now()).size() != 0));
    }
}
```

This throws an exception because of the Geocoder class is not mocked.

My question is how to approach this?

Should I just pass and Geocoder object to Helper like

```
new MyHelper(context, geocoder)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Pass the geocoder in the constructor or in a setter method. This is the way to achieve testability. This is a great talk that explains why you should do this always: http://youtu.be/RlfLCWKxHJ0